# How to determine which service to call

Tags: design, php, mongodb

I have modeled my application using multiple 'user' domain objects.

- Candidate
- Recruiter
- Administrator

Each entity extends from an `AbstractUser` implementing `UserInterface`.

```
interface UserInterface
{
    public function getEmail();
    public function setEmail($email);
    public function getPassword();
    public function setPassword($password);
}
```

They all have their own a services `CandidateService`, `AdminService` etc implementing `UserServiceInterface`

```
interface UserServiceInterface
{
   public function getUserByEmail();
}
```

My problem arises when I need to fetch a user by their email address (say `PasswordResetService`) I am unable to determine which service I should be calling as the email could be either of them. I am also using mongoDB so I cannot simply run a native query joining the 'tables'.

My current thought is that I have to inject each service into the `PasswordResetService` and call `getUserByEmail()` on each of them until I get my desired user.

```
class PasswordResetService
{
   public function getUserByEmail($email) 
   {
       $user = $this->userService->getUserByEmail($email);
       if ($user) return $user;

       $user = $this->recruiterService->getUserByEmail($email);
       if ($user) return $user;

       // etc ...
   } 
}
```

From a design perspective the above seems to me like a poor approach as should I add a new user 'type' I would need to update the password service also.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Do the services need to have different names?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I assume you mean within the context of `PasswordResetService`? So rather than `$this->userService` perhaps an array of user services? If this is what you mean, then no, they don't need different names as I would only ever be calling methods that are within the `UserServiceInterface`.

Comment: If the invoking functionality needs to be able to distinguish between the three types of actor, than you need to provide a mechanism allowing it. If it does not need to know (because you could call getUserByEmail directly for each, and similarly for every other service invoked), then you don't. I don't think there are any other good design choices.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by having a top level UserService that doesn't care what type of user it's dealing with.

If it gets a request for a user by email, it can look up on the database which type of user is correct and delegate the request to the correct service. This may sound a little inefficient, but used with an appropriate query caching later it's actually fine.

Other methods that are passed a user object could perhaps use [double dispatch](http://jes.st/2012/the-visitor-pattern-in-php/) to forward the request to the correct service object., thus eliminating the need to hit the database for these operations.